# Bandwidth Selection Methods

Tags: kernel-smoothing

Are there more methods for calculating the bandwidth in a kernel regression? So far I found Cross Validation Methods and a Bayesian approach (by Zhang, Brooks and King).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Literature has lots of other methods which performs very well in different manners. I am trying to clear this with some references...
Basically bandwidth selection methods can be categorized in two different categories; Classical and Plug-in (Hardle, 1990; Wand and Jones, 1995).These methods are also classified as first generation and second generation method; where “methods of first generation include rules of thumb, least squares cross-validation, and biased cross-validation, AIC, AIC_c, BIC,etc. and second generation has Solve-the-Equation Plug-In Approach and Smoothed Bootstrap (Jones et al. 1996).

Comment: Is this enough helpful for u? I can provide some more references for detail not only for univariate but also for multivariate case.

Comment: Sorry, just found your answer. It's very helpful! But if you have good references for the multivariate case, I would appreciate it. The more, the better :-)

Comment: Cross-Validation of Multivariate Densities. by Sain, et al. (1994). Journal of the American Statistical Association.

Comment: Thats great :) --- @To Mate can you mark as the answer .